# python interpreter: Does it convert and execute at the same time?

Tags: python

Does the python interpreter convert all of the source code into byte code at runtime before executing the byte code using PVM? Or does the interpreter convert and execute at the same time?

Comment: @AndrewLi nope, at least in CPython, the source is *compiled to bytecode first*, and then that bytecode is interpreted line-by-line

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Really? I thought interpreted languages had their source interpreted by an interpreter. TIL.

Comment: @AndrewLi modern languages are rarely purely interpreted or purely compiled. Rather, there is a mixture of both. See the discussion [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/24558/is-python-interpreted-or-compiled)

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thanks!